# Select row checkbox on each item select in Primefaces datatable cellEditor

Tags: primefaces, tablecelleditor, primeng-datatable

When I select an item in `datatable` with `editMode="cell"` (e.g. inputText , selectOneMenu) only that specific component is selected which is normal, but I want to select to whole row when I click on it, not just the component.

my problem is kind of UI related, there are specific areas on the row when you click on, the whole row gets selected, but when you click on the component in the row, only that component gets selected not the row and if you're collecting the object in backing bean, you don't have that row object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clientId from AjaxBehaviorEvent to get the index of the data.
ClientId is look like this

```
form:feeTbl:0:j_idt49
```

0 is the index. To get the index, you need to split it.

Comment: no that's not my problem, its about selecting the row instead of selecting a "part" of the row which is like selecting the component inside it.